# splitting a sql column with multiple select statements where value = x

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

My end result is to add the query results to a asp.net gridivew, c#.

I have a table with the following

```
updateID teamID empID shiftID
```

there are 9 teams with different shifts

I'm trying to split the database results so it returns values from the shift column based on the `teamID`

I'm not sure how to get the results to combine into 9 columns

```
Select shiftID as col1 from test1 where teamID = 1
Select shiftID as col2 from test1 where teamID = 2
Select shiftID as col3 from test1 where teamID = 3
Select shiftID as col4 from test1 where teamID = 4
```

etc

Can someone help with the best solution so I can add the results to a gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two possibilities:
make your pivot on your sql query : (easier way)
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

make your pivot on your dataTable that is datasource of your gridview in code but hare :
(a hard sample)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified

make a pivot directly on gridview isn't a good idea as for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to basically flip your table around so that you have the columns as rows and vice versa? That is called *transponse*. Maybe you can get your the data with one statement from SQL and transpose them after that. Maybe that link helps: http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/Pivot-or-Transpose-Rows-in-GridView-using-LINQ.aspx